# Allure generates an empty report Cucumber 7

Tags: maven, cucumber, allure

I've read almost all questions here and still did not find the answer.

I have the following pom:

```
....
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <selenium.version>4.7.2</selenium.version>
    <selenide>6.11.0</selenide>
    <allure>2.20.0</allure>
    <lombok>1.18.24</lombok>
    <slf4j.version>2.0.0-alpha6</slf4j.version>
    <rest.assured>5.1.1</rest.assured>
    <cucumber>7.11.1</cucumber>
    <allure>2.20.1</allure>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.9</aspectj.version>

</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

   ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-cucumber7-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${allure}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M8</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine> -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>${allure}</reportVersion>
                <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I run mvn clean test, get a results.
I also use Cucumber Reports feature, this feature grabs the results correcty, but not Allure.
Then call either allure serve or mvn allure: serve, but getting an empty report:[image: Report]

I really got stuck what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `cucumber.options="--plugin ...` to enable the Allure plugin.

This property was poorly designed replaced by individual properties in v5. For example `cucumber.plugin=com.example.MyPlugin`.

Unfortunately there are many old tutorials around. But [you should have seen a warning about this in the console.](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/2685) I added it 2 months ago.

If you don't see this warning at all there is a good chance you are not passing the property to the JVM that runs the tests. You may want to read the documentation for `argLine` and Surefire in general.

You can also put this property in either `junit-platform.properties` or `cucumber.propeties` depending which version of JUnit you use to run Cucumber.

Comment: Hello! Many thanks for your help, but anyway it didn't work for me. But I could figure out the way with the help of JUnit5 documentation.Anyway, as I see you're seems like a developer of Cucumber,so I am really-really curious, why there are zero really good guides on the Cucumber docs? Coz while Cucumber guidelines won't have a proper help, people will be using guides from the web. Warnings in the console are not clear as you see, I also did not have this prop to get the info about the deprecated CucumberOptions. So I do really think the Cucumber team may think about a good docs. Thank you!

Comment: Cucumber is an opensource project mostly developed by volunteers in their spare time. The project is only as good as what people want to contribute to it.

Comment: And while there is a team of regular core contributors it is only 5-7 people for more than 6 languages. If you want  to see improvement, the only way is to contribute those improvements.

Comment: Got it, then could you please share the place where I also can send a request for some doc guide, I mean, I can write an article for a review by more experienced guys and, if approved, to publish it somewhere. I do not mind to help coz I am maybe not super guru at Cucumber, but I have been working with this technology a lot, so I think I can share smth with the community, at least what I see, the issues I faced with and the ways I know right now how to fix them. ..

Comment: ...Especially with the new versions and challenges, because I have been working with Cucumber 4x many years and I feel like there are many people like my team, who finally decided to jump to the new version and got stuck at some points.

Comment: You can find the general docs here https://github.com/cucumber/docs

Comment: Release notes and updates here https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/release-notes

Comment: And other docs are in the readme file of each module or the java doc on the class you are using (your IDE should download those for you).